# how to prevent styling overlap

Tags: html, css, styling

I'm building an app with many different components and I've run into an issue where styling from one component has overlapped with styling from another component. Other than giving each paragraph tag it's own class, is there anyway to prevent this? Say with a keyword or something?

Comment: Can you share code, as well as your current and the expected result? I'd say, you'd need to use different classes for different components.

Comment: "styling from one component has overlapped with styling from another component" we have no idea what that means without some example code that reproduces your issue (other than guesses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use as a specific selector as possible in your CSS file. It isn't just .class or #div. When you find a more specific selector you can always add !important after all your style.

It will have a higher importance level than everything else, but you can still change it from a different file if you use the same level.

This can be something like this:

```
.some-div > p {
   font-size: 16px !important!
}
```

Please check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors for selectors.

Comment: It isn't bad, but this can be bad practice. If you take some CSS files with styles it will always be better to edit this file with a new style than to just use !important in a new one. Also if you set !important in your file, it will be hard to edit it in a new one. So it is just bad practice.

Comment: When you are forced to use `!important` "something is probably wrong" and should be considered a code smell IMHO.

Comment: I agree @MarkSchultheiss I had to use it in a Wordpress project and it was a pain :) Using separate styles is way easier, e.g. for base, document, layout, tables, etc.

Comment: That is also right what @MarkSchultheiss said, but also it is only one solution that will work if you don't add a unique class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any other way than giving unique class to every element.

**Let me elaborate**:

If you have used a web framework, say NextJs, you will see that it assign a unique class to every element to avoid class collision within page. And Styling IS one of them.

So yeah, Having unique classes IS necessary to avoid css collision, unless you don't go for an ID approach.